# Creating a dropdown from session attribute

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

In a sample spring mvc application i am setting a string list in the HttpSession in a controller and then trying to create a dropdown box in a JSP by trying to retrieve the same list from session. It's not working.

The code in the JSP is:

```
   <% java.util.ArrayList<String> userRoleList = (java.util.ArrayList<String>) request.getSession().getAttribute("ROLE_LIST"); %>
 <select name="userRole">
          <c:forEach var="role" items="${userRoleList}">
            <option value="${role}">${role}</option>
          </c:forEach>
        </select>
```

The list in the session has one string and if i print it in the JSP it displays one record as expected.
The output of,

```
<%= userRoleList %>
```

is

```
[ROLE_ADMIN]
```

But whatever i do dropdown box is always empty.
Hope someone can help.

Comment: While using an MVC framework like Spring MVC, use the features the framework provides as much as you can. Spring MVC supports its own tag which is easier to code and maintain in which you need not use JSTL `<c:forEach>` either.

Comment: Thank you Tiny. Will keep that in mind.

Comment: Scriplets are bad, don't use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use variable created in scriptlets in JSTL you must pass it in pageContext like this:

```
<% java.util.ArrayList<String> userRoleList = (java.util.ArrayList<String>) request.getSession().getAttribute("ROLE_LIST"); 
    pageContext.setAttribute("userRoleList", userRoleList);
%>
<select name="userRole">
    <c:forEach var="role" items="${userRoleList}">
      <option value="${role}">${role}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

But there is simplier solution for this:

```
<select name="userRole">
    <c:forEach var="role" items="${ROLE_LIST}">
      <option value="${role}">${role}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to write the `select` like this:

```
<select name="userRole">
    <% 
      java.util.ArrayList<String> userRoleList = (java.util.ArrayList<String>) request.getSession().getAttribute("ROLE_LIST");
      for(String role : userRoleList ) {
    %>
        <option value="<%=role%>"><%=role%></option>
    <% } %>
</select>
```